# multi column text fit to height and scroll page horizontally

Tags: css, html

[here is jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZLRp/) - red `div` will have given height in `px`. yellow will have a lot of content. I want yellow to be divided into `columns` (like newspaper) that has `height` of red `div`, has `margin` between them and if there is many of them I want them to make page scroll horizontally and red `div` has to have them inside itself, they cant `overflow`. (last one may be optional)

Comment: See the solution here, but be warn: you won't have support for that in IE http://xahlee.info/js/css_multi-column_layout.html

Comment: thats right that, but cross browser is really important in this case.

Comment: Then you can not achieve the newsletter layout without the help of javascript. I suggest the Columnizer plugin http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/ or any other from here http://webdesignledger.com/tools/10-jquery-plugins-to-help-with-web-page-layouts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove height, it shows same height of red & yellow.
you can check [on here:](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZLRp/1/)

```
#a{background:red;}
#b{width:200px; background:yellow;}
h1{font-size:40pt;}​
```